# Alternative #markup in a block's build function

Tags: 8, blocks

Version: Drupal 8.7.x

I am adding some canvas element to my page, and it gets ignored by Drupal. I can't even see it in the source page of browser.

If I have something like this in my code:

```
public function build(){
   $content = "<span>Something</span><canvas id='12' width='100' height='100'>
               </canvas>"
   return ['#markup'=>$content]; 
}
```

View page source will only shows

```
 <span>Something</span>
```

I was thinking that this might be an issue with the `#markup`. I was wondering if there are any alternative way to work with canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use #allowed_tags on the markup.

So put it like that:

```
  $content = "<span>Something</span><canvas id='12' width='100' height='100'>
               </canvas>"
   return [
     '#markup' => $content,
     '#allowed_tags' => [
       'canvas',
       'span'
     ]
   ];
```

not exactly sure if you need to add the span tag.

But also note that following is suggested as Drupal Best Practice from https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/group/theme_render/8.7.x:

> #markup: Specifies that the array provides HTML markup directly. Unless 
>   the markup is very simple, such as an explanation in a paragraph tag, it
>   is normally preferable to use #theme or #type instead, so that the
>   theme can customize the markup

And this is the explanation from Drupal regarding #markup and tags:

> Note that the value is passed through
>   \Drupal\Component\Utility\Xss::filterAdmin(), which strips known XSS
>   vectors while allowing a permissive list of HTML tags that are not XSS
>   vectors. (For example,  and  are not allowed.) See
>   \Drupal\Component\Utility\Xss::$adminTags for the list of allowed
>   tags. If your markup needs any of the tags not in this whitelist, then
>   you can implement a theme hook and/or an asset library. Alternatively,
>   you can use the key #allowed_tags to alter which tags are filtered.

Comment: Thank you so  much for taking your time and helping me. #allowed tags seems like the best way to approach this, but when I used it with canvas, only elements with canvas tags were displayed. So, I had to manually add all the fields I wanted to be displayed. Wish there was some wildcard or something. Once again thanks!

Comment: Then you might still go with creating your own theme implementation with hook_theme and use your twig-Template